# Why this python code is not executing through shell_exec in php?

Tags: php, parameters, shell-exec

I have been trying to run a python code that takes input from terminal like this
`python3 mycode.py input1 input2` and it perfectly works when I try it on terminal. But it is not working when I try it on php's `shell_exec`.
My php-

```
<?php 

$a = 'hello';
$b = 'world';

$output = shell_exec('python3 /path/to/mycode.py '.$a.' '.$b.'');
echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>';

?>
```

But it doesn’t output anything.
I have also tried adding

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

at the top of my python code and

```
sudo chmod +X mycode.py
```

but still not working.

**Edit:**
I found the problem but still don't know how to fix it. The mycode.py contains PIL module but it cannot be used on `www-data` user. So I tried `sudo chown -R chris:www-data /var/www/html/mysite` and now it is showing PIL module not found. How can I install PIL module for `www-data`?

Comment: As a first diagnostic, try to see what `shell_exec('which python3')` returns. As a sidenote, I strongly suggest using [`escapeshellcmd`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) on each argument (this is not a source of an error in this particular example since the arguments are known and simple, but it is absolutely recommended in real code).

Comment: @Amadan It returns `/usr/bin/python3` and `escapeshellcmd` is not working

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` function should return an array of the output of the command executed. With that I would recommend using `print_r()`.

Please try the following:

```php
<?php 

$a = 'hello';
$b = 'world';

exec('python3 /path/to/mycode.py '.$a.' '.$b, $command_output);
echo PHP_EOL;
print_r($command_output);
echo PHP_EOL;
?>
```

In an attempt to rule out a permissions issue you can also execute the php script from your terminal. Assuming you are using Apache whereas the service account is commonly `www-data` the account may not have access to the file you are attempting to execute.

If that doesn't work for you attempt running the php script as sudo. If that fails make sure to review your php logs for any clues.

Comment: I just found the problem. The module in the python code cannot be used by www-data for not having permission. Still don’t know how to fix this problem. Please check my edited question.